# Is Num special in this way?

Tags: haskell

I can create a `Num a => a` like this:

```
foo :: Num a => a
foo = 2
```

Similarly for any other number class:

```
foo :: Fractional a => a
foo = 2.0
```

However, I can’t think of a way to create something of type `Eq a => a`, `Ord a => a`, or anything non-number (without using `undefined`).

It seems to me that numbers are special in this way.

Are they?

Comment: Numeric literals are special syntax for `fromInteger` and `fromRational` - you can create a value of type `Num a => a` because you have a function `f :: Num a => .. -> a` (namely `fromInteger`). Precisely this same fact holds for any other typeclass. There are no such functions for `Eq` or `Ord`, that is, with the typeclass parameter in the return type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Num` isn't "special" in the sense that it is the only thing that it behaves this way. But it does have some characteristics that make it possible. Consider the `Bounded` typeclass instead. It is perfectly possible to define a similar function:

```
top :: Bounded a => a
top = maxBound
```

This is possible because `Bounded`, like `Num` but unlike `Eq`, provides as part of its class definition a way to create values of its type.

Answer (score 5):

There are many more examples:

```
def :: Default a => a
mempty :: Monoid a => a
maxBound :: Bounded a => a
toEnum 0 :: Enum a => a
read "" :: Read a => a
fromString "" :: IsString a => a
```

This is just off the top of my head. I'm sure there's many more.

Answer (score 1):

`Num` is special in that it has special syntax for writing literals. This syntax uses the function `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a` internally, which is defined in `Num`. The compiler parses what you have written into an `Integer`, and gives that to `fromInteger` to get the type you see.

The reason you can't do that with for example `Eq a => a` is there is no function in `Eq` that returns something of that type.

If you really need a value like that, you can use something like `data Equatable = forall e. Eq e => MkEquatable e` using the ExistentialQuantification extension, but that is probably not what you want to do.

Here is an example of a type class for which you can create a value with type `MyClass a => a`: [gist](https://gist.github.com/Lazersmoke/ce82856da2c3782e9735d4617ceb99f5)

Comment: The aside about existentials seems likely to cause confusion, and doesn't even appear to be related, since the question is about universals.

Comment: If you pattern match on MkEquatable, the variable inside will have type 'Eq a => a'. Since they specifically asked if that was possible, I wanted to make sure I covered all the possibilities.

Comment: It certainly will not. If that were so, you could cast a value of any `Eq` instance to a value of any other `Eq` instance; e.g. `MkEquatable True` is well-typed, so if `unEquatable :: Equatable -> (Eq a => a); unEquatable (MkEquatable e) = e` were well-typed as you say then `unEquatable (MkEquatable True) :: String` would be well-typed, but is clearly nonsense.

Comment: You are correct; that code will be rejected because e is a Skolem variable, so it isn't allowed to escape its scope. It isn't universal, but he wasn't asking for that, he was asking about 'Eq a => a'. You can, however, pass it to a polymorphic function. See [here](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/ExistentialQuantification) and consider 'SuchThat '[Eq] Identity' [here](https://gist.github.com/Lazersmoke/709c4cdd15d71389ba3f398075429a5d#file-ghostbuster-hs-L28)